# Informatica IPC - UNIX script fail

Tags: unix, session, ipc, informatica-powercenter

I have created a unix script to be executed after the session finished.
The script basically counts the lines of specific file and then creates a trailer with this specific structure:

T000014800000000000000000000000000000

T - for trailer

0000148 - number of lines

00000000000000000000000000000 - filler

I have tested the script in Mac, I know already that environments are totally different, but I want to know what is needed to be changed in order to execute this script successfully in IPC.

After execution I get the following error message:
**The shell command failed with exit code 126.**

I invoke the script as follows:

sh -c "$PMRootDir/scripts/exec_trailer_unix.sh $PMRootDir/TgtFiles"

```
#! /bin/sh

TgtFiles=$1
TgtFilesBody=$TgtFiles/body.txt
TgtFilesTrailer=$TgtFiles/trailer.txt

string1=$(sed -n '$=' $TgtFilesBody)
pad=$(printf '%0.1s' "0"{1..8})
padlength=8
string2='T'
string3=$(printf '%s%*.*s%s\n' "$string2" 0 $((padlength - ${#string1} - ${#string2} )) "$pad" "$string1")
string4='00000000000000000000000000000'
string5=$(printf '%s%*.*s%s\n' "$string3" 0 $((${#string3} - ${#string4} )) "$string4")
echo $string5 > $TgtFilesTrailer
```

Any idea would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points.

1. it looks like permission issue. Please login using informatica user(the user that runs infa demon) and run this command. You should be able to get the errors.

```
sh -c "$PMRootDir/scripts/exec_trailer_unix.sh $PMRootDir/TgtFiles"
```

2. Sometime the server variable $PMRootDir in UNIX doesnt get interpreted and can result null value. Please use `echo $PMRootDir` to check if its working after logging into UNIX using above user.
3. You can create trailer file using Infa easily.
   Just add an aggregator transformation right before actual target( group by a dummy field to calculate count(*)). Then add an  expression transformation to create those strings. And then trailer file target. Just 3 more transformations.

```
           | --> AGG --> EXP --> Trailer Target file
Final Tr --|--> Final Target
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Koushik Roy, I'll create a request to Admins so they can execute the line you sent. I took as a reference another scripts already created. 

For point 3, yes, in fact I already have a mapping that is based on a sql statement and it is working fine, but now the flat file is going to be changing during days, so the trailer should be based now on the file rather than data in source database.